# Visual Web Developer 2008 Express wanting SQL Server 2005 instead of 2008?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-express, visual-web-developer

When I double click on an mdf file on Visual Web Developer 2008 (NerdDinner.mdf) it says:

> Connections to SQL Server files (*.mdf) require SQL Server Express 2005 to function properly. Please verify the installation of the component or download from the URL: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=49251

The URL of course points to SQL Server Express 2008. I have that one installed and running. Any ideas why am I getting that message?

Comment: I can confirm that with SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 Express installed, with Visual Studio 2008, you cannot open MDFs, it asks for 2005 Express.

Comment: I am getting the same message and cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably installed Visual Web Developer 2008 Express with custom settings and skipped the database part.

Visual Web Developer 2008 Express was originally shipped with SQL Server Express 2005.
At the time, SQL Server Express 2008 wasn't ready yet.

Don't worry about the error message and just install SQL Server Express 2008.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know support for SQL Server 2008 was added in Service Pack 1 for Visual Studio.

You can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/).

Comment: I've installed Visual Web Developer from the Web Platform Installer yesterday, I would expect a fairly recent version, including SP1. On the about dialog of VWD I see it's version 9.0.30729.1 SP and that there are a bunch of SP1 entries in the list of installed products. Am I not running SP1 already?

Comment: I assumed you don't have SP1 since your problem is pretty common when it is not installed. Obviously you do have SP1 so my answer doesn't no solve the problem in your particular case. Sorry about that.